# Retrieve particular attribute from sqlite database to listview

Tags: android

i have this database file as below and also activity file in which i want to show stored name

```
package a.vaccination;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

public class datahandler {

public static final String KEY_ROWID = "id";
public static final String KEY_name = "name";
public static final String KEY_dob = "dob";
public static final String KEY_contact = "contact";
public static final String KEY_email = "email";
private static final String TAG = "DBAdapter";

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "profile";
private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "baby";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;

private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table baby(id integer 
primary key autoincrement, "
        + "name VARCHAR not null, dob date, contact VARCHAR, email  
VARCHAR);";
private final Context context;

private DatabaseHelper DBHelper;
private SQLiteDatabase db;

public datahandler(Context ctx) {
    this.context = ctx;
    DBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
}

protected static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {
            db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
            // db = DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
                + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old  
data");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS contacts");
        onCreate(db);
    }
}

// ---opens the database---
public datahandler open() throws SQLException {
    db = DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}

// ---closes the database---
public void close() {
    DBHelper.close();
}

// ---insert a record into the database---
public long insertRecord(String name, String dob, String contact,
        String email) {
    ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
    initialValues.put(KEY_name, name);
    initialValues.put(KEY_dob, dob);
    initialValues.put(KEY_contact, contact);
    initialValues.put(KEY_email, email);
    return db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
}

// ---updates a record---
public boolean updateRecord(long rowId, String name, String dob,
        String contact, String email) {
    ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
    args.put(KEY_name, name);
    args.put(KEY_dob, dob);
    args.put(KEY_contact, contact);
    args.put(KEY_email, email);
    return db.update(DATABASE_TABLE, args, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
}
public Cursor getAllTitles()
{
return db.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {
KEY_ROWID,
KEY_name,
KEY_dob,
KEY_contact,
KEY_email},
null,
null,
null,
null,
null,
null);
}
//---retrieves a particular title---
public Cursor getTitle(long rowId) throws SQLException
{
Cursor mCursor =
db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {
KEY_ROWID,
KEY_name,
KEY_email,
KEY_dob,KEY_contact
},
KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId,
null,
null,
null,
null,
null,null);
if (mCursor != null) {
mCursor.moveToFirst();
}
return mCursor;
}
}
```

and activity file where i want to retrieve name form database and show it in list view i done some coding but i stuck plz help me

```
package a.vaccination;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

//this shows profies of baby and option of add new one
public class profilelist extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener {

datahandler db = new datahandler(this);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.child);
    String nbaby[] = null;

    display();

    Button add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    ListView names = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

    ArrayAdapter<String> ad = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, nbaby);

    names.setAdapter(ad);
    names.setOnItemClickListener(this);

    add.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // navigate to create profile
            Intent it = new Intent(profilelist.this, 
createprofile.class);
            startActivity(it);

        }
    });

}

private void display() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    db.open();

    try {
        Cursor c = db.getAllTitles();
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                // System.out.println("bool2");
                DisplayTitle(c);
            } while (c.moveToNext());
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // System.out.println(e);
    }
    db.close();
}

private void DisplayTitle(Cursor c) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
//  System.out.println("bool");
    /*Toast.makeText(this,
    "id: " + c.getString(0) + "\n" +
    "ISBN: " + c.getString(1) + "\n" +
    "TITLE: " + c.getString(2) + "\n" +
    "PUBLISHER: " + c.getString(3),
    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();*/    

    nbaby[]=c.getString(0);


}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

}
```

Comment: What's ur problem..Its showing any error??

Comment: Do you get any error?

Comment: no i want to show stored name in list view which i define in profilelist.java

Comment: but i m stuck i don't get it how to do it

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
if(cursor != null){
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    String label = cursor.getString(1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try out below code: 
If you have not inserted any data into your database then first insert the data and then bind it into the listview. I have tried to insert some records in onCreate for my convenience. If you have already inserted the records then remove insertion code from onCreate().

I have stored all the values of the cursor into the `ArrayList<String>` and bind it into the listview. You can check out in below code. Its working perfect.

> ```
>   public class profilelist extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener
>     {
> datahandler db = new datahandler(this);
> String nbaby[] = null;
> ArrayList<String> m_arr=null;
> @Override
> protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
> {
>     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
>
>            db.open();
>     db.insertRecord("Texst", "10-1-1989","gaskudfgaskf", "teste@yahoo.com");
>     db.close(); 
>
>     display();
>     Button add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
>     ListView names = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
>     ArrayAdapter<String> ad =
>             new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, m_arr);
>     names.setAdapter(ad);
>     names.setOnItemClickListener(this);
>     add.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
>     {
>         @Override
>         public void onClick(View v)
>         {
>             // navigate to create profile
>         Intent it = new Intent(profilelist.this, createprofile.class);
>             startActivity(it);
>         }
>     });
>       }
> private void display()
> {
>     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
>     db.open();
>     m_arr=new ArrayList<String>();
>     try
>     {
>         Cursor c = db.getAllTitles();
>             c.moveToFirst();
>             do
>             {
>                 m_arr.add(c.getString(1));
>                  System.out.println("bool2"+c.getString(1).toString());
>                 } while (c.moveToNext());
>     }
>     catch (Exception e)
>     {
>         // System.out.println(e);
>     }
>     db.close();
> }
> ```